# Pointwise bounded family of continuous functions implies locally uniformly bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following Propostion which I am struggling to make sense of.

Let $(X, d)$ be a complete metric space, and assume that $F$ is a pointwise bounded family of continuous functions $f: X \to R$. Then there exists an open, nonempty set $G$ and a constant M $\in R$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in G$.

**Proof**: For each $n \in N$ and $f \in F$, the set $f^{-1}([-n,n])$ is closed, and so is $A_n = \cap_{f \in F} f^{-1}([-n,n])$. Since $F$ is pointwise bounded, $X = \cup_{n \in N} A_n$. Not all $A_n$ can be nowhere dense, so some $A_{n0}$ contains an open set, and the rest follows.

It's the part "Since $F$ is pointwise bounded, $X = \cup_{n \in N} A_n$" that I do not understand - I don't see how pointwise boundedness implies that the inverses hit all of $X$. I mean - the functions may not be injective and so not have inverses, how can we then use these undefined inverses to cover $X$? But if we $did$ suppose that each function was injective, then I could understand it.. However, I've also found [another proof](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hanche/notes/fnal/uniform-bound.pdf) of the proposition, so clearly you don't also need to assume injectivity to get the result. Can anyone help me see the implication? Or do you actually need injectivity for this particular proof to work?

Comment: It's not to be interpreted as inverse function notation, but rather as inverse image: $f^{-1}(E)=\{ x \mid f(x)\in E\}$.

Comment: Ah yes. My book even states that in the opening chapter. Somehow the distinction has escaped me all this time.. Incredible. And embarrassing. Thank you sir!